# C# Powershell host, capturing output of launched console apps

Tags: c#

I've written a custom powershell host that provides a winforms-based interactive shell. The examples MSDN were excellent and I was able to get something working in a few hours.

All of the standard built-in commands like dir, etc work as expected. However, when I try to launch another console app,like the FTP client, that app starts sending output to stdout. I can see this by changing the application type in VS from windows to console. As soon as I launch FTP from my interactive shell, FTP starts talking to the console window.

Anyone tackled this before? In C++ I could just redirect stdin and stdout and be done with it, but I don't see a way to do this in c#. Help!

**update**

Okay, anything I run that is not a built-in command immediately starts interacting with the console window.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, maybe it can help

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "netstat";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Thanks. That works well for cmd.exe and other executables, but not for PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the Powershell part

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a working example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dotnetinterop/wpf-invokes-powershell-exe-as-an-inferior-shell)! While it doesn't use the Powershell classes in the .NET framework, it does exactly what I need, including successfully capturing io from launched console apps.